# Parse xml data from xsd data structure?

Tags: php, xml, import, xsd

I have to import around 10 000 database entries from a xml file but with xsd file data structure, how can I use correctly xsd file to import xml data? I use PHP.

This is my xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2010 rel. 3 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="shopInformations">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>All products</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="productInformation">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="productcode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="content"/>
                            <xs:element name="sections">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:element name="section">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="title"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="public"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="reseller"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="lang" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="en"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="es"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My xml file has around 450MB and I cannot open it...

Comment: way too broad and not a snippet of code in sight! I would guess you can use `DOMDocument` and iterate through the nodes but without seeing the data nobody is going to be able to really offer an answer

Comment: Can you add any code you currently have.  Not everyone is going to write the code for you.

Comment: @NigelRen I added now xsd example and tried with DOMDocument but I can't find the way to use xsd as a map for xml import...

Comment: OK - so do you have a set of database tables, or the particular bits of data you need to extract?

Comment: I will created tables, it's a new project, but I'm confused how to read this data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the details are a bit vague, I've had to guess quite a bit, but to read such a large file, it's better to use XMLReader to do this.  XMLReader allows you to read the file in segments rather than reading the whole file in one go.

The following code show a simple way of reading the data, but as I have had to create some test data from the XSD - it may not be exactly correct.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('t1.xml');
while( $xml->read() ) {
    if($xml->name == "productInformation") {
        $product = $xml->readOuterXML();
        $prod = new SimpleXMLElement($product);
        echo "title=".$prod->title.PHP_EOL;
        echo "author=".$prod->author.PHP_EOL;
        echo "productcode=".$prod->productcode.PHP_EOL;
        echo "content=".$prod->content.PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $prod->sections->section as $section)    {
            echo "section id=".$section['id'].PHP_EOL;
            echo "section title=".$section->title.PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo PHP_EOL;
        $xml->next();
    }
}
```

If your going to use values returned by SimpleXML, you may need to cast the value, so `$prod->title` when being assigned to a string field would need to be `(string)$prod->title`

Comment: That means I can simple read xml without to use directly xsd file?

Comment: An xsd file is purely something which defines what the xml file should conform to.  You can use it to validate your XML, but don't need it to read it.